# Python Regex not working to extract information from a wiki page

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get a block of text out of a string. I'm trying to use:

```
def findPersonInfo(self):
    if (self.isPerson == True):
        regex = re.compile("\{\{persondata(.*)\}\}",re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE|re.UNICODE)
        result = regex.search(self._rawPage)
    if result:
        print 'Match found: ', result.group()
```

The string is: (yes, its a wiki page)

```
*[http://www.jsc.nasa.gov/Bios/htmlbios/acaba-jm.html NASA biography]

{{NASA Astronaut Group 19}}

{{Persondata
|NAME= Acaba, Joseph Michael "Joe"
|ALTERNATIVE NAMES=
|SHORT DESCRIPTION=[[Hydrogeologist]]
|DATE OF BIRTH={{Birth date and age|1967|5|17}}
|PLACE OF BIRTH=[[Inglewood, California]]
|DATE OF DEATH=
|PLACE OF DEATH=
}}
{{DEFAULTSORT:Acaba, Joseph M.}}
[[Category:1967 births]]
```

but I keep getting no matches.

Comment: Just a couple of style comments: 1) you can drop the parens around the condition (Python `if` statements don't need them, as shown in your second `if result:`), 2) unless you really want to compare if `self.isPerson` is `True` and no other value, you should simply use `if self.isPerson: ...`, 3) PEP 8 [recommends](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names) using the `find_person_info` and `self.is_person` naming convention, 4) regexen are usually specified with raw `r'...'` strings to avoid backslash escaping issues.

Comment: One more thing: the local variable `result` won't be set (and hence will cause an exception) if `self.isPerson` is false. Did you intend the second `if` to be indented one more level?

Comment: @benhoyt - Thanks for the comments, I'm new to python so still learning all the python style conventions. The 2nd if should be indented one more level :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `re.DOTALL` to the regex options:

```
In [193]: regex = re.compile(r"{{persondata(.*)}}",re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE|re.UNICODE|re.DOTALL)

In [194]: regex.search(text).group()
Out[194]: '{{Persondata\n|NAME= Acaba, Joseph Michael "Joe"\n|ALTERNATIVE NAMES=\n|SHORT DESCRIPTION=[[Hydrogeologist]]\n|DATE OF BIRTH={{Birth date and age|1967|5|17}}\n|PLACE OF BIRTH=[[Inglewood, California]]\n|DATE OF DEATH=\n|PLACE OF DEATH=\n}}\n{{DEFAULTSORT:Acaba, Joseph M.}}'
```

`DOTALL` causes `.` to match any character at all, including the newline. (Without `DOTALL`, `.` does not match newlines.)

`MULTILINE` causes `^` to match the beginning of lines as well as that of the string, and `$` to match the end of lines as well as that of the string. That's okay but it does not influence the match here.

PS. The backslashes are not necessary, so for the sake of readability, I've omitted them.

PPS. If the `findPersonInfo` method is called a lot, you may want to lift the call to `re.compile` out of the method since it does not depend on `self`:

```
class Foo:
    info_pat = re.compile("{{persondata(.*)}}",
                                  re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE|re.UNICODE)
    def findPersonInfo(self):
        result = None
        if self.isPerson:
            result = self.info_pat.search(self._rawPage)
        if result:
            print 'Match found: ', result.group()
```

Comment: Much more info than I expected. I learned a lot about python regex from this. Thank you